# How to insert values into SQL Server table using Stored procedure in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, table-valued-parameters, sqlalchemy-pytds

I am new to `pytds`. Facing `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string` issue while inserting data into SQL Server.

**Issue I am getting is:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:/Users/mydesk/Desktop/test/test_pytds.py", line 64, in 
> connect_and_call_stored_procedure(query, val)
> File "c:/Users/mydesk/Desktop/test/test_pytds.py", line 48, in call_sproc
> cursor.execute(query, (tvp,))
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytds_*init*_.py", line 739, in execute
> self.*execute(operation, params)
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytds_*init**.py", line 701, in _execute
> operation = operation % names[0]
> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Something I missed. Let me know your valuable inputs.

**My complete code:**

```
import pytds 
def get_query() -> str:
    sql = '''
        DECLARE @tbl [dbo].[tbl]
        insert into @tbl
        (
            col1, col2, col3
        )
        values (%s,%s,%s)
    '''  
    query += '''
         EXECUTE [dbo].[stproc] 
         @tbl
    '''
    return sql

def call_sproc(query, val):
    server = 'my_server'
    user = 'my_user'
    password = 'secret'
    database = 'my_db'
    
    try:
        conn = pytds.connect(server=server, user=user, password=password, database=database)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        tvp = pytds.TableValuedParam(type_name='dbo.tbl', rows=val)

        cursor.execute(query, (tvp,))

        conn.commit()

        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

    except pytds.Error as e:
        print("Connection issue:", e)

###
val=[('col1_val'), ('col2_val'), ('col3_val')]
my_sql = get_query()
call_sproc(my_sql, val)
```

Comment: `cursor.callproc("dbo.stproc", (tvp,))` https://python-tds.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pytds.html or if you still want to use an ad-hoc batch then do `cursor.execute("EXECUTE [dbo].[stproc] %s", (tvp,))`

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, Thank you. If I mention the stored proc in `callproc` my insert is not running. is anything to change ?

Comment: Well I'm somewhat confused by your current code. You hav a TVP already, why are you trying to create a new one using `DECLARE...INSERT...` why not just pass the TVP straight to the procedure?

Comment: yah got it Charlie. I removed Insert query and it is working fine.
Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To call a stored procedure, you don't need any query or `DECLARE`. Just do what [the docs say](https://python-tds.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pytds.html) and use `callproc`

```py
cursor.callproc("dbo.stproc", (tvp,))
```

Or if you really want to use an ad-hoc batch then do

```py
cursor.execute("EXECUTE dbo.stproc %s", (tvp,))
```